# My C code doesn't output anything, or end running

Tags: c, terminate

I'm trying to answer this question:

The prime factors of 13195 are 5, 7, 13 and 29.

What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int isPrime(long long num)
{
    for (long long k = 1; k < num; k++)
    {
            if (num%k == 0)
                    return 0;
    }

    return 1;
} 
long long num = 600851475143;
int main(void)
{
    long long prime_factor = 0;
    for (long long j = 2; j < num; j++)
    {
            if (num % j == 0 && isPrime(j) == 1)
                    prime_factor = j;
    }

    printf("%lli\n", prime_factor);


}
```

But for some reason it doesn't print anything, or even end.  What is causing this?

Comment: The sheer number of loops you are asking it to do.

Comment: I would love an explanation about why `long long num` is global?

Comment: Oh, your code is running.  You're just asking it to do many, many, *many* calculations before you output anything.  Brute force loops are not how you solve this particular Project Euler problem.

Comment: long long num is global because I am a dummy @iharob

Comment: I though it was a Project Euler problem, but wasn't sure...

Comment: @user3630559 that's what I thought.

Comment: You could easliy find ways to reduce the work. 1) iterate only up the (precalculated) square root. 2) only test odd divisors. 3) ditto for `isPrime`

Comment: @WeatherVane also, the primes could be pre-generated and stored instead of computing them on each iteration.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into another solution @David

Comment: Hint: Once you've calculated a prime, there's no need to ever calculate it again.  You can *store* the result of the calculation.  Second hint: A lot of numbers are *obviously* not prime and don't need to be calculated to determine that fact.

Comment: And I aslo suspect that **the largest** means something, don't you think so?

Comment: @David ok, I'll try that.  I just thought that "good code" didn't have any hard coded numbers like that, and that it was better and more versatile to have the program do it.

Comment: `isPrime` is faulty - it will show *any* number to be prime.

Comment: Sort of off topic question, why is this question getting downvoted?  I'm new to StackOverflow, and just wanna know so I can more effectively use the site later.  Is it because my question was too easy/stupid?  Was I too vague?  Thanks for all of your responses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a terribly inefficient way of finding the prime factors of a number.

To find the prime factors, you should:

> 1. Create a static list of primes less than or equal to (number / 2).
> 2. Iterate over each element in the list of primes and see if each
>       one can evenly divide the number.
> 3. Divide the original number by the prime, and check the last number 
>      again.

Why? Well the smallest prime is 2. If the number isn't even then the first prime that can divide any number > 2 is 3.

Every number can be uniquely identified by its prime factors. This is called the [Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic). That means that there is only one way to represent e.g. 15 as a product of primes, in this case { 3, 5 }.

However any prime can divide a number more than once. For example, 49 is the product of two primes { 7, 7 }. Dividing the original number by one of its factors makes subsequent divisions quicker. And you can logically stop checking when the number == 1.

Comment: The first prime factor of your number is 71. Hint: There are 4.

Comment: No need to go up to `(number / 2)`, up to `sqrt(number)` will suffice.

Comment: I was a bit vague, sorry. I wasn't talking about finding primes. I was talking about finding the prime factors of a number. To find the prime factors of 13714, we have to check up to (13714 / 2) to find the prime factor 6857.

Comment: You would have found that with the very first `2`. If you want to check for factors check `2` then iterate the odd numbers up the the square root. Beyond that you will already have checked the other factor.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't print anything because it never leaves the loop, after which is found the only line which prints anything in the code. Try a smaller number and see if it ends.